# I have firebase user id, but I can't access name

Tags: firebase, swift2, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

So I'm making a chat app, and I need to access the user's name. But I only have the users ID. Is there any way I can search through the entire database and find a user with the same id as I have?

[Firebase Tree Setup Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLOVc.png)

this is my firebase tree setup. So I have the users id: eg. 1JIalS7s85PgucxZgGi48ao9Oaf2

However, I don't have the user's name: eg. DummyBoy

Is there a way to find the name

Comment: What do you mean you only have the id? is the id an attribute for the user? or is it the key for the user?

Comment: Give your JSON tree..

Comment: Firebase Authentication provides no public API to look up a user's name by their uid. For this reason many developers store a list of users in their Firebase Database, as Callam's answer shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the names of your users like this.

```
{
    "users": {
        "{uid}": {
            "name": "John"
        }
    }
}
```

Now using a user's uid, you can get their name in swift like this:

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().referenceWithPath("users/\(uid)/name")

ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
    if let name = snapshot.value as? String {
        print(name)
    }
})
```

Comment: stack trace please?

Comment: One thing though, I need to use this in a variable, so I did

Comment: var messageSenderName: String?

Comment: messageSenderName = name

Comment: but it gave me a screen without any messages